# Substitute a column i text file with incrementing numbers

Tags: linux, text-processing

I need to do something very similar to this [Replace string with sequential index](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117106/replace-string-with-sequential-index?newreg=e0ab2a24ef7640b29ef2a0c64064890e), but I don't need to add a number to a column, but substitute a whole column with incrementing numbers. Like this:

```
0   0   chr1    3000575 3000801 0   chr1    4340023 4340249 32  32  
0   0   chr1    3000641 3000801 -1  chr1    3311943 3311783 32  32  
0   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32  
0   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32  
0   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32
```

becomes

```
0   0   chr1    3000575 3000801 0   chr1    4340023 4340249 32  32  
1   0   chr1    3000641 3000801 -1  chr1    3311943 3311783 32  32  
2   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32  
3   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32  
4   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32
```

(I don't care whether it starts with 0 or 1)

I feel very stupid, but I can't adjust the solution from that question to my case...

Comment: What separates the columns? Spaces or tabs?

Comment: Columns are separated by tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To number lines, you may use `nl`.  To remove columns (or rather filter out the ones you want to keep), you may use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f 2- cols.txt | nl
     1  0       chr1    3000575 3000801 0       chr1    4340023 4340249 32      32
     2  0       chr1    3000641 3000801 -1      chr1    3311943 3311783 32      32
     3  0       chr1    3000674 3000801 -1      chr1    3001534 3001407 32      32
     4  0       chr1    3000674 3000801 -1      chr1    3001534 3001407 32      32
     5  0       chr1    3000674 3000801 -1      chr1    3001534 3001407 32      32
```

The only annoying thing with `nl` is that it inserts space padding at the start of the line (by default, the line number field is 6 characters wide, and you don't want to lower this because it would truncate the line numbers). We may get rid of these like so:

```
$ cut -f 2- cols.txt | nl | sed 's/^ *//'
1       0       chr1    3000575 3000801 0       chr1    4340023 4340249 32      32
2       0       chr1    3000641 3000801 -1      chr1    3311943 3311783 32      32
3       0       chr1    3000674 3000801 -1      chr1    3001534 3001407 32      32
4       0       chr1    3000674 3000801 -1      chr1    3001534 3001407 32      32
5       0       chr1    3000674 3000801 -1      chr1    3001534 3001407 32      32
```

The `cut` utility takes a list of columns that you want to "cut out of" the input.  In our case it's columns 2 and onwards (`-f 2-`).  Since your data is tab-delimited, `cut` will do this without modification, otherwise it's possible to tell it to use another delimiter with `-d`.

The `sed` command will simply substitute those spaces at the start of the line from `nl` with nothing.

Comment: I compared time it took for these two commands, and although user time was similar, real time was smaller here, so accepted, thanks!

Comment: @Phlya `awk` is actually too big a beast for doing simple things sometimes.

Comment: I know it is, I am just not familiar with it unfortunately!

Comment: @Phlya forgot to mention that the output is all still tab-delimited. `nl` puts a tab after the line number by default.

Comment: @Phlya You're working on genomic data. If the line numbers get too big, increase the width for `nl` with `nl -w 10`.

Comment: I am, there are ~200-300 mln lines. What do you mean by too big?

Comment: @Phlya `nl` uses 6 characters for the line numbers and will truncate them if they get bigger than '999999'. With `nl -w 10` you would allow for line numbers ranging from 1 to 9999999999.

Comment: Maybe on my system the default is different, but I get longer numbers without this parameter, but thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`

```
$ awk '{$1=FNR-1; print}' OFS='\t' file
0   0   chr1    3000575 3000801 0   chr1    4340023 4340249 32  32
1   0   chr1    3000641 3000801 -1  chr1    3311943 3311783 32  32
2   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32
3   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32
4   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32
```

Comment: Seems like the other answer is a little faster, so accepted it, but thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

With `ed` (using a literal tab, composed as <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, in the substitution)

```
$ ed -s file << EOF
,s/0    //
,n
q
EOF

1   0   chr1    3000575 3000801 0   chr1    4340023 4340249 32  32  
2   0   chr1    3000641 3000801 -1  chr1    3311943 3311783 32  32  
3   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32  
4   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32  
5   0   chr1    3000674 3000801 -1  chr1    3001534 3001407 32  32
```

The `(.,.)n` command prints the addressed lines, preceding each line by its line number and a tab - perfect for your tab-delimited format.