# Selection of line from pattern, replacement with new line and incrementing number for each change

Tags: text-processing

Hi I'm trying to work out how to select a line in a text file from a pattern/word string, and then replace that line with new text with an incrementing number for each line changed.

I was planning on using sed, but have no idea how to implement the increasing number for every line changed.

The aim, before and after:

Text before:

```
">text_1_lots of other bits of text"   
other lines of text   
">text_2_lots of other bits of text"    
other lines of text   
">text_3_lots of other bits of text"   
other lines of text
```

Text after:

```
">text_1"   
other lines of text   
">text_2"    
other lines of text   
">text_3"   
other lines of text
```

This is what I have so far:

```
sed -i "s/>text_*/>text_[0-n]/g"
```

I realise this doesn't work as the `[0-n]` and wildcard `*` are just representing what I'm trying to do, and are the closest things that I can think of to achieve that (even though I understand this is essentially pseudo code at the moment)

Comment: yes, this is because i figured it would be easier to remove the line and replace it, than to just delete the rest of that specific line after the <text_n . however if there is a simpler code to carry out this deletion then I would much prefer to use that. although would also still like to know how to do the above just out of curiosity.

Comment: Are you trying to remove whatever follows  `>text_[number_here]` (so keep the number but remove the rest ?

Comment: You can easily "trim" the lines while preserving the original numbering e.g. `sed -E 's/(>text_[0-9]{1,}).*/\1/' file`

Comment: ideally yes, but only remove the rest of the text of each specific line. I had a quick look into it, and the best i could find was a find and replace type method with sed.

Comment: What should be the output in case you have lines beginning: text 2, text 1, text 3, text 3, text 5? The behavio[u]r in this case is different for all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your attempt with sed, it looks like the patten you're trying to match is `">text_` and you want to append a number and a `"` after that

This is do-able with `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN {cnt=1} /^">text_/ { gsub("_.*$","_"cnt++"\"",$0) } { print}'
```

e.g.

```
$ cat x
">text_lots of other bits of text"
other lines of text
">text_lots of other bits of text"
other lines of text
">text_lots of other bits of text"
other lines of text

$ awk 'BEGIN {cnt=1} /^">text_/ { gsub("_.*$","_"cnt++"\"",$0) } { print}' x
">text_1"
other lines of text
">text_2"
other lines of text
">text_3"
other lines of text
```

You can change the search pattern `^"text_` to identify the lines you want to change, and the `gsub()` call will do the replacement; in this case from the first `_` to the end of the line is replaced with `_` then the count then a `"`

Comment: this works nicely, i realise now from above comments that there defintily is a simpler method to achieve my aim. however this does answer the question i asked, and has helped my understanding to do more complex text editing in the future (and of course worked nicely too). so much appreciated Stephen.

Answer (score 4):

`perl` can do this with a similar syntax to that of `sed`, but allowing straightforward evaluation of the replacement index e.g.

```
perl -pe 's/>text_.*/sprintf "text_%d", ++$n/pe' file
```

See also [Replace string with sequential index](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117106/replace-string-with-sequential-index/117107#117107).

However since in your case the text is already numbered, it's easier just to trim the unwanted portion by capturing and resubstituting it - for example

```
sed -E 's/(>text_[0-9]+).*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest would be to use bash or perl. Simple bash example that should get you going with your probably more complicated problem:

```
$ cat script 
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while read a ; do
    if [[ "$a" =~ "\">text_${i}".* ]]
    then echo "\">text_${i}\"" ; i=$((i+1))
    else echo "$a"
    fi
done
$ cat input 
">text_1_lots of other bits of text"
other lines of text
">text_2_lots of other bits of text"
other lines of text
">text_3_lots of other bits of text"
other lines of text
$ cat input | bash script 
">text_1"
other lines of text
">text_2"
other lines of text
">text_3"
other lines of text
```

Comment: If you're using `while..read` you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @don_crissti I'll use any tool that does the job.

Comment: See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -pe 'state $i; s/^ \" \> text_ .* /"text_{++$i}"/;'  file
```

*OR:*

```
~$ raku -pe 'state $i; s/^ \" \> text_ .* /{sprintf "\"text_%d\"", ++$i}/;'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. The second answer above is basically a translation of @steeldriver's excellent Perl5 code.

Briefly, Raku's `-pe` sed-like autoprinting commandline flags are used. Non `<alnum>` characters in Raku regexes must be escaped, however regex atoms can be spread out as they are whitespace tolerant (equal to Perl's `\x`). A counter variable `$i` is `state`d, meaning it is only instantiated once (can use a BEGIN block here instead, e.g. `BEGIN my $i;`). The replacement should be self-explanatory:  Raku code is interplolated within `{`…`}` curly-braces.

Sample Input:

```
">text_A_lots of other bits of text"   
other lines of text   
">text_B_lots of other bits of text"    
other lines of text   
">text_C_lots of other bits of text"   
other lines of text
```

Sample Output:

```
"text_1"
other lines of text   
"text_2"
other lines of text   
"text_3"
other lines of text
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org